# Old events getting appended every time similar event occurs on submit

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I was trying to make a to-do list in vanilla JS. There's an Add button to add items in the list. While the edit option is selected for a particular item, the add button changes to edit and the input box accepts the edited value.

When I edit first item it works fine. But when I edit the second item, the first as well as the second items value changes. Same goes when third item is edited, the second and first items value too changes. I'm not sure why is this happening.

```js
const todoForm = document.querySelector('.todo-form');
// select the input box

const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
// select the <ul> with class="todo-items"

const todoItemsList = document.querySelector('.todo-items');
const butt = document.querySelector('.add-button');

let todos = [];
todoForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    if(butt.innerHTML === "Add"){
        console.log("Add");
    e.preventDefault();
    AddTo(todoInput.value);
    console.log(todoInput.value);}
});

function AddTo(item){
    console.log(item);
    if(item!= ''){
        const todo = {
            id : Date.now(),
            name : item,
            completed : false
        }

        todos.push(todo);
        addToLocal();
        todoInput.value = '';
    }
}

function renderTo(){
    todoItemsList.innerHTML = '';
    todos.forEach((item) => {
        const checked = item.completed ? 'checked' : null;

        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.setAttribute('class','item');
        li.setAttribute('data-key', item.id);

        if(item.completed == true){
            li.classList.add('checked');
        }

        li.innerHTML = `<input type = "checkbox" class = "checkbox" ${checked}> ${item.name} <button class = "delete-button">X</button> <button class = "edit-button">E</button>`;
        todoItemsList.append(li);

    })

}

function addToLocal(){
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    renderTo();
}

function getFromLocal(){
    const reference = localStorage.getItem('todos');

    if(reference){
        todos = JSON.parse(reference);
        renderTo()
    }


}

getFromLocal();

todoItemsList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target.type === 'checkbox'){
        toggle(e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-key'));
    }

    if(e.target.classList.contains('delete-button')){
        del(e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-key'));
    }
    if(e.target.classList.contains('edit-button')){
        edit(e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-key'));
    }
})

function toggle(id){
    todos.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.id == id){
            item.completed = !item.completed;
        }
    });
    addToLocal();
}

function del(id){
    todos = todos.filter((item) => {
        return item.id != id;
    });
    addToLocal();
}

function edit(id){
    butt.innerHTML = "Edit";
    todos.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.id == id){
            todoInput.value = item.name;
            console.log(item);
            todoForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(item);
                item.name = todoInput.value;
                addToLocal();
            })
        }
    })
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  body {
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: linear-gradient(#F00000, #DC281E);
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  
  button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #73E831;
  }
  
  ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
  /* get rid of bullet points on side of list items */
  
  }
  
  /* common style ends */
  
  
  /* container */
  
  .container {
    min-width: 700px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  
  /* todo-form */
  
  
  .todo-form {
    margin: 40px 0px;
  }
  
  .todo-input {
    width: 250px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  
  .add-button {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  
  /* todo-form style ends */
  
  
  /* todo-items */
  
  .todo-items {
    min-width: 350px;
  }
  
  /* each li with class="item" */
  
  .item {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  
  .item:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  }
  
  .item:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  }
  
  /* item style end */
  
  
  .checkbox {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  .delete-button {
    float: right;
    background-color: #dc143c;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 550;
  }
  .edit-button {
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 550;
  }
  
  /* applied when the todo item is checked */
  
  .checked { 
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Todo</h1>

    <form class="todo-form">
      <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="Add a Todo...">
      <button type="submit" class="add-button">Add</button>
    </form>

    <ul class="todo-items">
      
<!-- dummy item -->

      <li class="item" data-key="1594003133171">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
        Go to Gym
        <button class="delete-button">X</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new 'submit' event listener for each selection and never clean them.

Each selection **adds a new event listener to the existing ones**

See change in edit method, or see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtw6uf05/6/)

```js
const todoForm = document.querySelector('.todo-form');
// select the input box

const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
// select the <ul> with class="todo-items"

const todoItemsList = document.querySelector('.todo-items');
const butt = document.querySelector('.add-button');

let todos = [];
todoForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    if(butt.innerHTML === "Add"){
        console.log("Add");
    e.preventDefault();
    AddTo(todoInput.value);
    console.log(todoInput.value);}
});

function AddTo(item){
    console.log(item);
    if(item!= ''){
        const todo = {
            id : Date.now(),
            name : item,
            completed : false
        }

        todos.push(todo);
        addToLocal();
        todoInput.value = '';
    }
}

function renderTo(){
    todoItemsList.innerHTML = '';
    todos.forEach((item) => {
        const checked = item.completed ? 'checked' : null;

        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.setAttribute('class','item');
        li.setAttribute('data-key', item.id);

        if(item.completed == true){
            li.classList.add('checked');
        }

        li.innerHTML = `<input type = "checkbox" class = "checkbox" ${checked}> ${item.name} <button class = "delete-button">X</button> <button class = "edit-button">E</button>`;
        todoItemsList.append(li);

    })

}

function addToLocal(){
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    renderTo();
}

function getFromLocal(){
    const reference = localStorage.getItem('todos');

    if(reference){
        todos = JSON.parse(reference);
        renderTo()
    }


}

getFromLocal();

todoItemsList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target.type === 'checkbox'){
        toggle(e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-key'));
    }

    if(e.target.classList.contains('delete-button')){
        del(e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-key'));
    }
    if(e.target.classList.contains('edit-button')){
        edit(e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-key'));
    }
})

function toggle(id){
    todos.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.id == id){
            item.completed = !item.completed;
        }
    });
    addToLocal();
}

function del(id){
    todos = todos.filter((item) => {
        return item.id != id;
    });
    addToLocal();
}

function edit(id){
        console.log(id)
    butt.innerHTML = "Edit";
    todos.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.id == id){
                
            todoInput.value = item.name;
            console.log('in for', item);
            const listener = (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('submit', item);
                item.name = todoInput.value;
                addToLocal();
                todoForm.removeEventListener('submit', listener) //<-- clear listener when its done
            }
            todoForm.addEventListener('submit', listener)
        }
    })
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  body {
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: linear-gradient(#F00000, #DC281E);
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  
  button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #73E831;
  }
  
  ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
  /* get rid of bullet points on side of list items */
  
  }
  
  /* common style ends */
  
  
  /* container */
  
  .container {
    min-width: 700px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  
  /* todo-form */
  
  
  .todo-form {
    margin: 40px 0px;
  }
  
  .todo-input {
    width: 250px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  
  .add-button {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  
  /* todo-form style ends */
  
  
  /* todo-items */
  
  .todo-items {
    min-width: 350px;
  }
  
  /* each li with class="item" */
  
  .item {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  
  .item:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  }
  
  .item:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  }
  
  /* item style end */
  
  
  .checkbox {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  .delete-button {
    float: right;
    background-color: #dc143c;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 550;
  }
  .edit-button {
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 550;
  }
  
  /* applied when the todo item is checked */
  
  .checked { 
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Todo</h1>

    <form class="todo-form">
      <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="Add a Todo...">
      <button type="submit" class="add-button">Add</button>
    </form>

    <ul class="todo-items">
      
<!-- dummy item -->

      <li class="item" data-key="1594003133171">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
        Go to Gym
        <button class="delete-button">X</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was wondering why don't we remove the listener while adding new elements?

Comment: to remove all listeners in any addition, you'll need to keep track of the listener callback. it will be the safest way